# replacing certain images with certain words

Tags: php

i want to change the word :)) to a smily img before displaying it from database with php how can i do that

Comment: http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/1834/

Comment: @MYYN, that example uses the `ereg_` function. 1) I see no need for regex in this case, and 2) when using regex, it's advised to choose the `preg_` family over the `ereg_` since the  latter is either already deprecated or soon will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution would be to use the [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/str_replace) function.

For instance *(Using "`:-)`", which I like more than your "`:))`" -- only a matter of taste ^^ Up to you to use the "right one")* :

```
$str = "This is a sentence with a smiley :-)";

$new_str = str_replace(
    array(
        ':-)', 
    ), 
    array(
        '<img src="smiley.png" alt=":-)" />'
    ),
    $str
);

echo $new_str;
```

Will get you this output :

```
This is a sentence with a smiley <img src="smiley.png" alt=":-)" />
```

i.e. the smiley has been replaced with an image.

Note that I used an array for the first and second parameter, when calling `str_replace` : if you have other smileys, you can just add them to those two arrays *(the first array being for the "searched" string, and the second for the "replacement")*.

*(What I mean is : no need to call `str_replace` several time : one time, using arrays, should be enough for several replacements)*

And, as a sidenote : I used the original "text" of the smiley for the `alt` attribute of the `img` tag : this way, if the image cannot be displayed, the browser will display the textual version of the smiley -- which is better than nothing.

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN: Beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
str_replace(':))', '<img src="path to your image" title="image title" />', $string);
```

If you want to replace multiple 'smileys', use arrays:

```
$find = array(
            ':)',
            ':('
        );
$replace = array(
               '<img src="path to happy image" title="" />', 
               '<img src="path to sad image" title="" />');
           );
str_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following. Create a new replacement for each image you've got.

```
$message = str_replace(":)", "<img src='happy.png' alt=':)'/>", $message);
$message = str_replace(":(", "<img src='unhappy.png' alt=':('/>", $message);
```

This will turn `$message` `"I'm happy :)"` into `"I'm happy <img src='happy.png' alt=':)'/>"`. The alt tag reveals the original smiley when users don't see images.